# Python string split multiple brackets

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I am looking for a simpler / faster way to split a string by brackets / parenthesis, as well as removing white spaces and useless info.

More specifically, I want to change

```
[ 5 * * ]{t=0, 1 }{t=0, 3 }{t=0, 2 }
```

to two part:

```
 5 * *   (or [ 5 * * ])
['1', '3', '2']
```

I managed to do this using my code:

```
test = '[ 5 * * ]{t=0, 1 }{t=0, 3 }{t=0, 2 }  '
parsed =  test.split("[")[1].split(']') 
index = parsed[0]
content = parsed[1].split('{')[1:]
seq=[]
for i in range(len(content)):
    seq.append(content[i][4:-2].replace(' ', ''))   
print index
print seq
```

which gets:

```
 5 * * 
['1', '3', '2}']
```

---

I'm looking for suggestions to modify my code. It would be ideal if:

1. There would be **no loop**.
2. **Less 'split'**. (There are three 'split' functions in my code)
3. **More general**. (I used content[i][4:-2] to remove '{' and '}' which is not general )

Comment: Define "useless info."

Comment: Looks like you're going to need some RegEx. Make an attempt using that and add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you pzp. Sorry about not explaining useless. In this case, useless info is " t=0,  "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` and a list comprehension  :

```
>>> l=re.findall(r'\[([^\]]*)\]|,([^}]*)}',s)
>>> [i.strip() for j in l for i in j if i]
['5 * *', '1', '3', '2']
```

The following regex :

```
r'\[([^\]]*)\]|,([^}]*)}'
```

will match everything between brackets (`\[([^\]]*)\]`) and between comma and `}` (`,([^}]*)}`).

Or you can use `re.split()` :

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'[{},[\]]',s) if i and '=' not in i]
['5 * *', '1', '3', '2']
```